# How can i display a textview coming from an expandable listview when i click on one particular item?

Tags: android, textview, expandablelistview

What can i do if i want to click on one item(say Avatar movie) out of several items in an expandable view and then a textview appears about description of the(Avatar movie) BUT DESCRIPTION SHOULD APPEAR ON NEXT ACTIVITY and the same repeats for the other items.

Answer (score 0):

Do following steps

1. Grab the selected  value (let it be avatar movie) and send it to next activity by `putExtra` of Intent. Its like

   ```
   Intent intent = new Intent(SendingActivity.this,RecievingActivity.class);
   intent.putExtra("keyName", "avatar movie"); 
   startActivity(intent);
   ```
2. Get the value from Intent on second activity

   ```
   Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
   if(extras != null)
   String data = extras.getString("keyName");
   ```
3. Get the description related to `avatar movie` or whatever was  selected  in second activity.

Comment: Well first of all these are present in my project:FirstAcitivity.java,Activity_main.xml,parent_layout.xml,child_layout.xml‌​, MyAdapter.java. :) Now my problem is that i don't know WHERE TO PLACE your given codes in my project...Also please tell me whether i should CREATE another activity like in your codes(say Activity2.class and Activity1) to place your given codes because when i copy and pasted this i got errors. Thank you :)